# Can't get Longitude from Google Places API Details search

Tags: php, google-places-api

I am trying to get the longitude and latitude of locations using the Google Places API details search. Here is the code I am using to retrieve the place details from the API:

```
$selectedLocationDetails = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='. $selectedLocationID .'&key=MyKey'), true);
```

This successfully gets the details of the location however it is only displaying the 'lat' not the 'lng', below is what a var_dump of the $selectedLocationDetails looks like for the geometry section.

```
["geometry"] array(1) {
    ["location"] array(2) {
        ["lat"] 54.582309
    }
}
```